# How to check html form if its re-dirtied?

Tags: html, angularjs

(using angularJs 1.6)
I have a form that has some controls, and a save button.
When I click save, i check to see if the form is dirty.
If its dirty, then i save the changes off to a database, then set the form.dirty to false.

I also have if form is dirty, and user tries to navigate away without saving, there is a warning message that the form has not been saved.

If i navigate away after saving and come back everything works as expected.
But if I change something, then save. Then change something else.  The form does not go dirty without refreshing first.

Comment: Without seeing your code how are we supposed to guess what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, I can only answer based on what you mentioned and therefore you shouldn't be changing the form's `$dirty` property manually.

You should use the `$setPristine();` method instead.

As mentioned in [AngularJS Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setPristine):

> Setting a form back to a pristine state is often useful when we want to 'reuse' a form after saving or resetting it.

Which sounds like what you are attempting to do.